# jQuery enable/disable submit button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using jquery to disable the submit button and the registration. I want to remove the bank detail, account number, and ifsc code. But when I remove those fields, the submit button not click(hit). I want to remove disabled prevention. please help me out

```
function registerMember() {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    $('#nxt3dddd').prop('disabled',true);
    var flag="yes";

    $('.inp').each(function(){
        var a=$(this).val();
        if(a==""){
            flag="no";
            $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
            $('#nxt3dddd').prop('disabled',false);
        }else{
            $(this).css('border','1px solid #d2d6de');
        }
    });
}
```

In submit button I am using the following :

```
<div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;margin:inherit">
   <button type="submit" id="nxt3dddd" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" style="width:100px;float:right">Submit</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doesn't call function **registerMember()** in `onclick()` event of **button** and add a `input` text having named **inp**

```js
function registerMember() {
    $('#nxt3dddd').prop('disabled',true);
    var flag="yes";

    $('.inp').each(function(){
        var a=$(this).val();
        if(a==""){
            flag="no";
            $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
            $('#nxt3dddd').prop('disabled',false);
        }else{
            $(this).css('border','1px solid #d2d6de');
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;margin:inherit">
   <input class="inp" type="text" />
   <button type="submit" id="nxt3dddd" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" style="width:100px;float:right" onclick="registerMember()">Submit</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: OP is already setting the *property* (and not the attribute). From https://api.jquery.com/prop/: "*The `.prop()` method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the `.attr()` method.*"

Comment: let me check bro :) please wait

Comment: please try now bro